# Converting a curl to Python requests.put

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I've looked up several things, and I'm just not finding one that's doing exactly what I'm doing.  I've found ones that are close, but I can't seem to get it.

I have this curl statement.  It returns a 204 when successful, and it works fine.

```
# curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"latitude":47.629355,"longitude":-122.3794778}' "http://myserver.com/location/private/location"
```

When I try to convert it to Python Requests, it seems it should be as follows:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = {"latitude":'47.629355',"longitude":'-122.3794778'}
r = requests.put("http://myserver.com/location/private/location", headers=headers, data=data)
```

However that's failing and returning a 400 (bad request).  So something isn't quite right with how I've formed it.

I've continued to poke at it, changing quotes, etc.  But based on what I've read on SO and on http://docs.python-requests.org/, it looks to me like I'm doing it right.

Any wisdom to share would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You're providing the lat/long in the curl call as a float, yet in your python code as a string. Try with: `data = {"latitude":47.629355,"longitude": -122.3794778}`. Code looks fine otherwise.

Comment: That was what I originally had for data as well, and it didn't work.  I tried again just to make sure I didn't miss it, and is still doesn't work.  Still getting a 400.

Comment: Printing r.text shows me this "Invalid request: Unable to read number: latitude=47.629355&longitude=-122.3794778"

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing `data` with `json.dumps(data)`:

```
import json
r = requests.put("http://myserver.com/location/private/location", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

ARGH!!!

Found the error.  In the curl, I was passing:

```
'{"latitude":47.629355,"longitude":-122.3794778}'
```

In the request.put I was passing:

```
{"latitude":47.629355,"longitude":-122.3794778}
```

I was missing the external quotes that ran the whole thing together into what my services were expecting.